# Laravel 5 Eloquent HasManyThrough - name columns in links

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.1

UPDATE: After looking at the Eloquent hasManyThrough class, without changing it, I cannot see how I could link the tables below. The declarations of params for the method call is:

```
class HasManyThrough extends Relation
{
    /**
     * The distance parent model instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
     */
    protected $farParent;  // in my case: User::class

    /**
     * The near key on the relationship.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $firstKey;  // in my case: organisation_users_roles(organisation_id)

    /**
     * The far key on the relationship.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $secondKey;  // in my case: users(id)

    /**
     * The local key on the relationship.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $localKey;  // in my case: organisation(id)
```

So there is no way to tell the standard Eloquent `hasManyThrough` that first link is `organisation(id)->organisation_users_roles(organisation_id)`
and second link is `organisation_users_roles(user_id)->users(id)`

Did I misunderstand?

---

I cannot find an example of the syntax to use if you have three tables linked via `hasManyThrough` and the column names in each table do not follow the Eloquent naming convention. In my case:

Three tables:

```
Organisations
Users
Roles
Organisation_Users_Roles (3 way linking)
```

Because these belong to an already existing app, I cannot change / rename columns.

The linking column names are:

```
`Organisation: id` links to `Organisation_Users_Roles: organisation_id"
`Users: id` links to `Organisation_Users_Roles: user_id"
`Roles: id` links to `Roles: role_id"
```

The `Organisation_Users_Roles` also contains an `id` column (essentially its primary key or row id).

I have tried (as example) in `Organisation` class:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(User::class, OrganisationUserRole::class);
}
```

In the docs example the tables are:

```
countries
    id - integer
    name - string

users
    id - integer
    country_id - integer
    name - string

posts
    id - integer
    user_id - integer
    title - string
```

So, in the example:

`country(id)->users(country_id)`
and
`users(id)->posts(user_id)`

And in my case:

`organisation(id)->organisation_users_roles(organisation_id)`
and
`organisation_users_roles(user_id)->users(id)`

But since the column names are not exact to the example on Eloquent Docs (as this is a three way linking table) then I get the following error when using the method:

```
[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.user_role_id' in 'on clause'
```

I want to get the first returned user for the current Organisation, I call it like this:

```
$entry['created_user_id'] = $organisation->users->first();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your organisation table, try

```
return $this->hasManyThrough('App\..path-to..\User', 'App\..path-to..\Organisation_Users_Roles', 'organisation_id', 'id' );
```

Comment: Hi Bharat, it does not work. I get `users.user_id` not found.

Comment: Hi Bharat, this returns null, which is incorrect. The query works but the link between two of the tables is incorrectly built (`user_role`.`id` = `users`.`id`)