# Laravel 5.1 - Class Method not working

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.1

UPDATE: This works:

```
$var = Organisation::whereId($org->id)->first()->id
```

But really I wanted

```
$var = $org->users()->first()->id;
```

---

I have a class called `Organisation`, with the following method:

```
  /**
    * Organisation has many users
    *
    * @return Collection
    */
   public static function users()
   {
       return static::join('organisation_user_role', 'organisations.id', '=', 'organisation_user_role.organisation_id')
           ->join('users', 'user_role.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
           ->select('users.*');
   }
```

I call it like this from a table seed routine:

```
$entry['created_user_id'] = $org->users()->first();
```

The variable $org contains a single row in Collection form:

```
   $orgs = Organisation::all();

   foreach ($orgs as $org) {
      .....       
      $entry['created_user_id'] = $org->users()->first();
   }
```

When I do a

```
dd($org->users()->first());
```

I get `null` which is incorrect based on the data I have (confirmed via manual queries).

There is no syntax error with the above but it is not working. I am trying to get the users for the current Organisation record.

What have I missed? I have been playing with Laravel 5.1 for a month or so now, so learning fast!

My tables and columns are:

```
organisations
  - id
  - title
  - address
  - city
  - state
  - logo
  - softdelete columns

users
  - id
  - name
  - email
  - password
  - softdelete columns

roles
  - id
  - slug
  - title
  - softdelete columns

organisation_user_role (3 way linking)
  - id (essentially row number)
  - organisation_id
  - user_id
  - role_id
  - softdelete columns
```

Comment: Why don't you use a proper Eloquent relationship here?

Comment: I am using a pre-existing app and modifying. The tables created do not lend themselves to a `hasManyThrough`. Please see this Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301816/laravel-5-eloquent-hasmanythrough-name-columns-in-links

Comment: What other columns do you have in your `user_role` table?

Comment: Hi Ross, have a look at my prev question, where I was trying to use hasManyThrough. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301816/laravel-5-eloquent-hasmanythrough-name-columns-in-links

Comment: Do you have any other columns in your `user_role` table apart from `organisation_id` and `user_id`? I just had a look at your previous question, however, I couldn't see it in there.

Comment: Hi Ross, I have placed the tables/columns in the question above. Thanks for the help.